# What is the difference between Vec3b and Scalar in opencv?

Tags: c++, opencv

There are different types in opencv, Vec2b , Vec3b. Vec4i and so on, and there is the Scalar type. From what I understand, Vec3b and Scalar are both types for storing three numbers together. So, if I want to access a pixel (in RGB format) I am simply writing `image.at <Vec3b> (x,y)=Vec3b ( number, number, number)`, the same goes for Scalar, but what is their difference, is there even a difference at all?
   I am asking this since I am having some weird experiences with using Vec3b and Scalar, when I am suing Scalar ( I am trying to convert some pixels into grayscale but leave the image in RGB format ) by doing this 
`image.at<Scalar>(x,y)=Scalar( gray_image.at<uchar>(x,y), gray_image.at<uchar>(x,y), gray_image.at<uchar>(x,y));` ( I have the same image in grayscale called gray_image), but this appears to give some weird results, on the other hand when I am using Vec3b instead of Scalar I am getting normal results. Why is that happening?

Comment: besides, use `Mat1b`, `Mat3b`,  etc when possible to avoid `.at<type>`

Comment: Scalar is 4 elements to represent BGRA values typically and is mostly used as INPUT element where the functions just uses the channels of the Scalar which are needed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html A `Scalar_` is

> Template class for a 4-element vector derived from `Vec`.

Which

> Being derived from `Vec<_Tp, 4>`, `Scalar_` and `Scalar` can be used just as typical 4-element vectors. In addition, they can be converted to/from `CvScalar` . The type `Scalar` is widely used in OpenCV to pass pixel values.

Where as a `Vec` is:

> Template class for short numerical vectors, a partial case of `Matx`:

And

> The `Vec` class is commonly used to describe pixel types of multi-channel arrays. See `Mat` for details.

So they are and are not the same.